# Storing datetime in a mysql server play framework

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, playframework-2.0

I have a Play application connected to a mysql server, in the models I have some attributes that I would like to be saved as DateTimes, however using java.sql.Timestamp produces attributes in my evolutions for the creation of a tables

```
 create table delivery (
  id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
  deleted                   tinyint(1) default 0,
  description               varchar(500),
  notes                     varchar(1000),
  account_id                bigint,
  customer_id               bigint,
  sender_id                 bigint,
  recipient_id              bigint,
  delivery_status_id        bigint,
  delivery_type_id          bigint,
  package_type_id           bigint,
  item_type_id              bigint,
  call_date                 datetime(6),
  pickup_date               datetime(6),
  delivery_date             datetime(6),
  no_of_pieces              integer,
  cust_type                 integer,
  payment_type              integer,
  way_bill                  integer,
  created_time              date,
  modified_time             date,
  createdby_id              bigint,
  modifiedby_id             bigint,
  constraint pk_delivery primary key (id))
```

which in turn leads to the mysql error:

> We got the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '(6), modified_time datetime(6), createdby_id
>   bigint, mo' at line 21 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000], while trying to
>   run this SQL script:

I learned that it was the size parameter (6) causing the problem and was able to avoid it by using java.sql.Date (since it does not produce in the evolutions) has anyone else experienced this and know a way of storing a DateTime under these conditions?

Comment: Please post more SQL script. Also, what is the exact query your application is trying to execute?

Comment: I don't see why you insist in using java DateTime, can you explain?

Comment: It was that I wanted to store a datetime rather than just the date or time and both java.sql.Date and java.sql.Timestamp were causing this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around the problem by using the @Column annotation to define the the type in sql.

```
    @Column(columnDefinition = "datetime")
    public Timestamp createdAt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probaly my answer is a bit late, but you can try using the following annotations: @CreatedTimestamp or @UpdatedTimestamp. I've tested it with Play! Framework 2.3.x.

```
@Column(name = "created")
@CreatedTimestamp
protected Date created;

@Column(name = "updated")
@UpdatedTimestamp
protected Date updated;
```